# Haskell: read [Double] from binary file

Tags: haskell, binary

I have a file with binary data (more precisely, it's a npy file = header data + raw binary data). This data ([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4] for tests) can be successfully readed by this code in C++ (skipped):

```
int word_size = 8;
double *data;
arr = new char[size*word_size];
size_t nread = fread(arr, word_size, size, file);
if(nread != size)
    *data = reinterpret_cast<double *>(arr);
```

I'm trying to implement this in Haskell:

```
data Header = Header {
    {- other fields -}
    npyData         :: [Double]
    } deriving (Show)

getNpyData = do
    empty <- isEmpty
    if empty
        then return []
        else do 
            v <- getWord64be
            rest <- getNpyData
            return (fromIntegral v : rest)

npyHeader :: Get Header
npyHeader = do
    {-other fields -}
    npyData <- getNpyData
    return Header {
        {- other fields -}
        npyData=npyData
    }


main = do
    file <- openBinaryFile "test.npy" ReadMode
    input <- BL.hGetContents file
    let npyParsedData = runGet npyHeader input
    print $ npyData npyParsedData
```

This gives to me incorrect results for `npyData` (other variables are ok):

```
[1.1140104038263667e19,1.114010403826367e19,3.6893488147419515e18,1.1140104038263675e19]
```

Can anybody tell me, what is wrong in this code?

Comment: I just came across this article [(link)](http://ruhaskell.org/posts/utils/2015/01/15/npy-parsing.html) on parsing npy files in Haskell. It's in Russian, but Google translate seems to do a decent job.

Comment: Thx, but this is my article, partially based on this question =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try the `getFloat...` and `getDouble...` functions from the `cereal` package [(link)](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cereal-0.4.1.1/docs/Data-Serialize-IEEE754.html).

What your code is doing is reading a 64-bit integer value and converting that do a Double.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, what should work

```
     v <- get :: Double
```

doesn't since `Data.Binary` doesn't use an IEEE754 encoding of doubles (it stores the result of `decodeFloat`).  Hence a good choice is to use the cereal package.  At least within GHC I've gotten `unsafeCoerce` on a `Word64` to work for similar tasks as well.

```
    bitsToDouble :: Word64 -> Double
    bitsToDouble = unsafeCoerce
```

Probably `cereal` is a safer way of doing this.